# Install PHP-Payments in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, payment

I'm working on a project, using CodeIgniter, that will have to process credit card payments, both for one-off purchases and also for recurring payments. I stumbled across Sparks and the codeigniter-payments spark yesterday. I got Sparks and the code-igniter spark installed, but then discovered there were no config files in the directory the documentation said they should be in - not even a sample config.

After emailing the author, he explained that I needed to get the latest version from github using the --recursive switch, which I promptly did (and am thoroughly appreciative of his response). However, it turns out that the project has become PHP-Payments, which is independent of the Sparks framework.

The usage information in the PHP-Payments documentation advises to use an include statement:

```
include('/path/to/payments/payments.php');
```

As far as I know, this will not work in CodeIgniter. Has anyone else got experience using PHP-Payments in their CodeIgniter project? If so, where in the CodeIgniter directory structure do you recommend I put the PHP-Payments files? Did you use an include statement as suggested by Calvin? Or did you use the typical CodeIgniter syntax of:

```
$this->load->
```

Thank you in advance, as I've never used a third-party plug-in in CodeIgniter before.

Also, I checked the version of PHP my host is running and it is v5.2.17. I am aware the PHP-Payments project relies on late static bindings and that this feature is not available in PHP versions earlier than 5.3.0. So, I've contacted my host about getting PHP upgraded to a newer version and, if they are unwilling or unable to do this, then I'll move my project to a host that is running a version >=5.3.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [sparks](http://getsparks.org/packages/codeigniter-payments/show) (it will go in your sparks folder, not libraries):

php tools/spark install -v0.1.4 codeigniter-payments

Once you've installed, follow the instructions in the sparks link.

Other alternatives:

1. Include PHP-Payments outside of CodeIgniter and require it
2. Put it in a third party package and load from there

Answer (score -1):

I have never used PHP Payments, but from my CI experience I would say the files belong in the libraries folder.

You can create a new library fairly easily. 
- [CodeIgniter Libraries Documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html)

CodeIgniter does require you to follow their naming conventions, so you may have to create Class for yourself so you can load the library and access PHP Payments functions you wish to use in your controllers.

I have installed the basic PayPal and Authorize.net API's as libraries before and it worked just fine.

Comment: OK. I am trying this. PHP-Payments has its primary files inside a directory /lib, which is at the same level as its other directories (/config, /tests, /vendor, etc). Will CodeIgniter be able to load the library class if it is in /libraries/lib/class_file.php ? It seems to me that it would only be able to load it when it is /libraries/class_file.php, but I could be wrong. Thank you again!

Comment: Files do not belong in library folder.  Either install via sparks / command line (as it was intended) or put into third party.